# How to specify a few methods for ControlFlowPointcut constructor?

Tags: java, spring, aop

Reading a book of "Pro Spring" came to an example

> Pointcut pc = new ControlFlowPointcut(ControlFlowDemo.class, "test");

It's clear how it works, but question is  - is it possible (and how) to point out a few methods in constructor? I mean what if I would like 1 pointcut that works for 3 methods (test1(2,3)). For instance like:

> Pointcut pc = new ControlFlowPointcut(ControlFlowDemo.class, "test, test2, test3");

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the constructor that doesn't specify a method name, which will then match all control flows for the class?

Comment: Seems I haven't read about it yet. Could you please show an example or link to the option?

Comment: This constructor: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/aop/support/ControlFlowPointcut.html

Comment: @azurefrog, matching all control flows might not be what the OP wants, because if he wants to filter for regex `test.*` or more exactly `test[1-3]`, the pointcut would be too unspecific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. `ControlFlowPointcut` does not offer you to call it with multiple method names or to specify a pattern. The method name must match exactly, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9c0825629b715949b7082201bbcd90bfbf9d660b/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/support/ControlFlowPointcut.java).

What you can do, however, is

- to switch to native AspectJ and use the existing `cflow` and `cflowbelow` pointcuts there, or
- to copy and modify the source code. I was curious, so I did that for you. I tried to extend it at first, but some members which should be `protected` in that class or at least have accessor methods for better extensibility, are actually `private`, i.e. I would have ended up duplicating existing code. So I simply copied and extended it:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q68431056;

import org.springframework.aop.ClassFilter;
import org.springframework.aop.MethodMatcher;
import org.springframework.aop.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Pointcut and method matcher for use in simple <b>cflow</b>-style pointcut.
 * Note that evaluating such pointcuts is 10-15 times slower than evaluating
 * normal pointcuts, but they are useful in some cases.
 *
 * @author Rod Johnson
 * @author Rob Harrop
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Alexander Kriegisch
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut implements Pointcut, ClassFilter, MethodMatcher, Serializable {

  private Class<?> clazz;

  @Nullable
  private String methodName;

  @Nullable
  private Pattern methodPattern;

  private volatile int evaluations;


  /**
   * Construct a new pointcut that matches all control flows below that class.
   * @param clazz the clazz
   */
  public MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(Class<?> clazz) {
    this(clazz, (String) null);
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new pointcut that matches all calls below the given method
   * in the given class. If no method name is given, matches all control flows
   * below the given class.
   * @param clazz the clazz
   * @param methodName the name of the method (may be {@code null})
   */
  public MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(Class<?> clazz, @Nullable String methodName) {
    Assert.notNull(clazz, "Class must not be null");
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.methodName = methodName;
  }

  /**
   * Construct a new pointcut that matches all calls below the given method
   * in the given class. If no method name is given, matches all control flows
   * below the given class.
   * @param clazz the clazz
   * @param methodPattern regex pattern the name of the method must match with (may be {@code null})
   */
  public MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(Class<?> clazz, Pattern methodPattern) {
    this(clazz, (String) null);
    this.methodPattern = methodPattern;
  }

  /**
   * Subclasses can override this for greater filtering (and performance).
   */
  @Override
  public boolean matches(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Subclasses can override this if it's possible to filter out some candidate classes.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isRuntime() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass, Object... args) {
    this.evaluations++;

    for (StackTraceElement element : new Throwable().getStackTrace()) {
      if (
        element.getClassName().equals(this.clazz.getName()) &&
        (this.methodName == null || element.getMethodName().equals(this.methodName)) &&
        (this.methodPattern == null || this.methodPattern.matcher(element.getMethodName()).matches())
      ) {
        //System.out.println("Control flow match: " + element.getClassName() + "." + element.getMethodName());
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * It's useful to know how many times we've fired, for optimization.
   */
  public int getEvaluations() {
    return this.evaluations;
  }


  @Override
  public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public MethodMatcher getMethodMatcher() {
    return this;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut)) {
      return false;
    }
    MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut that = (MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut) other;
    return (this.clazz.equals(that.clazz)) &&
      ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.methodName, that.methodName) &&
      ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.methodPattern, that.methodPattern);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = clazz.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (methodName != null ? methodName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (methodPattern != null ? methodPattern.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Most of the code is identical to the original, except for the following parts:

- new field `@Nullable private Pattern methodPattern`
- new constructor `public MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(Class<?>, Pattern)`
- `equals(..)` and `hashCode()` consider `methodPattern`
- `public boolean matches(Method, Class<?>, Object...)` considers `methodPattern`

So if now you instantiate this class with

```java
new MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(
  ControlFlowDemo.class, Pattern.compile("test.*")
)
```

or

```java
new MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut(
  ControlFlowDemo.class, Pattern.compile("test[1-3]")
)
```

it should do exactly what you want.

**Implementation notes:**

- Instead of a new `Pattern` field + constructor, I could have simply treated the existing `String` field as a regex pattern by default, but despite being backwards compatible that would slow down exact method name matches. Maybe that would be negligible, I did not measure it.
- The regex syntax is inconsistent with AspectJ or Spring AOP syntax which only has simple `*` patterns, not full-blown regex ones. But if you are sporting your own custom pointcut class, you can just as well use something more powerful.
- Of course, it would be easily possible to extend the implementation to also allow pattern or subclass matching for the `Class` part, not just the `Method` one. But that would also slow down pointcut matching even more.
- Uncomment the log statement in method `matches(Method, Class<?>, Object...)`, if you want to see which method in the control flow triggered advice execution.

---

**Update:** I have created [Spring issue #27187](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27187) in order to discuss, if the core class could be either extended or be made more easily extensible in order to avoid duplication.