# How to define a Pointcut to pick out all methods invoked by the specified method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

Is there any way to define a pointcut in AspectJ that would pick out each method directly executed by a specified method?

For example if there is a `parentMethod()` in `classA` that looks like:

```java
public void parentMethod() {
    classB.methodX();
    classC.methodY();
}
```

I want to define a pointcut that uses just the information about `parentMethod` to pick out whenever its invoked methods, `methodX()` and `methodY()`, are executed. Is there a way to achieve this using AspectJ pointcuts?

Comment: Please provide more details on expected output ? Do you want to identify every line of execution of parentMethod implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we are not talking about inheritance, so you should not call it a "parent method". You simply mean a method calling other methods, do you not? Anyway, concerning your question:

With Spring AOP you have limited means of expressing control flow pointcuts, compared to native AspectJ's `cflow()` and `cflowbelow()` pointcuts. In your case and if you want to stick with proxy-based Spring AOP, a `ControlFlowPointcut` might be enough, because you do not need any method name patterns but seem to have a fixed method name as your target. For more information, see:

- Section "update 2" of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66649082/1082681) for basic pointers to resources concerning `ControlFlowPointcut`.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68434674/1082681), if you want to match method patterns with a custom `MultiMethodControlFlowPointcut` (currently still unsupported by Spring out of the box).
- Spring manual chapter ["Using AspectJ with Spring Applications"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) explains how to configure Spring to use native AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW).
- If you decide to go the native AspectJ LTW way, the AspectJ manual section about [control-flow-based pointcuts](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5393) briefly explains `cflow` and `cflowbelow`.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using AspectJ AOP to fulfill my requirements.